# AutoViML - Just starting out, getting an error and not able to understand why I am getting it

Tags: python-3.x

The data is wish eCommerce sales data and every cell contains data.

'''

```
model, features, trainm, testm = Auto_ViML(
    train=df,
    target="units_sold",
    test="",
    sample_submission="",
    hyper_param="RS",
    feature_reduction=True,
    scoring_parameter="weighted-f1",
    KMeans_Featurizer=False,
    Boosting_Flag=True,
    Binning_Flag=False,
    Add_Poly=False,
    Stacking_Flag=True,
    Imbalanced_Flag=True,
    verbose=3
)
```

'''

This is the code I am using and the error I am getting is

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-68-551b071b5af3> in <module>()
     12     Add_Poly=False,
     13     Stacking_Flag=True,
---> 14     Imbalanced_Flag=True,
     15 
     16 )

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in _iter_indices(self, X, y, groups)
   1713         class_counts = np.bincount(y_indices)
   1714         if np.min(class_counts) < 2:
-> 1715             raise ValueError("The least populated class in y has only 1"
   1716                              " member, which is too few. The minimum"
   1717                              " number of groups for any class cannot"

ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Auto_ViML has detected this as a classification problem since "units-sold" might have just a few unique values ("classes"). In that case, it is not able to split the dataset into train and test since some classes are so few in number that some buckets have only one class. Can you please check your input and try again.